# Jquery Datatable and Google BOT

Tags: jquery, seo, googlebot

I'm using jquery [Datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) plugin to load posts dynamically with pagination(Ajax Calls). Here is [example](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/pipeline.html). But I'm worried about SEO. There is no anchor tag for moving to the next Page, Only a button which execute a Ajax call to populate the table with next rows. I wonder, How google BOT will pickup my all the posts inside the pagination ? What should i do to guide BOT to read all posts ?

Answer (score 1):

Just turn off Javascript in your browser and then you will see your page as it see google bot.

In any case you can make navigation for browsers without javascript support. This will good for SEO and good for users without JS.

Answer (score 1):

By providing Html_Snapshots you can now have GoogleBot process your datatables with server side data.

> Googlebot can (now) execute JavaScript and parse content generated by
>   Ajax.

[reference on google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started?hl=fr)

Comment: Thanks, Happy to know now this become possible